# Assign same key to Duplicate records for identification in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my customer data, there are duplicate records based on several key fields like same email address, phone or mailing address for different records. I want to identify sets of duplicate records based on repeating email, phone or mailing address and assign them a repeating number(same id) to mark them as repeating customers. After doing this, i want to move just unique customer records to another table which will have no duplicates and serve as master record table.

I am able to use dense_rank to rank duplicate records with same number but
got stuck afterwards, don't know how to assign new keys to NewCustID for all records.

Initial Tables and sample data

```sql
create table Cust_init(
    NewCustID int,
    DW_CustID int,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Email varchar(50),
    MailAddress varchar(50),
    Phone varchar(50)
)

create table MergedCust(
    NewCustID int,
    DW_CustID int,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Email varchar(50),
    MailAddress varchar(50),
    Phone varchar(50)
)


insert into dbo.cust_init(DW_CustID,FirstName, LastName,Email,MailAddress,Phone) 
values(11,'Ahmad','Raza','ahmaddba@gmail.com','154 Zafarwal, Narowaal','0345 2876543'),
      (12,'Iftikhan','Khan','iffikhan@gmail.com','12 A DHA Phase ','0303 56871298'),
      (13,'Iftikhan','Khan','iffikhan@gmail.com','12 A DHA Phase ','0303 56871298'),
      (14,'Mohsin','Khan','mohsinkaz@gmail.com','55 shadab nagar, Lahore','0301 6791255'),
      (15,'Mohsin','Khan','mohsinkaz@gmail.com','55 shadab nagar, Lahore','0301 6791255'),
      (16,'Hamid','Alvi','hamidalvi@gmail.com','12 A DHA Phase 2','0300 7071266'),
      (17,'Hamid','Alvi','hamidalvi@gmail.com','12 A DHA Phase 2','0300 7071266'),
      (18,'Hamid','Alvi','hamidalvi@gmail.com','12 A DHA Phase 2','0300 7071266'),
      (19,'Hamid','Alvi','hamidalvi@gmail.com','12 A DHA Phase 2','0300 7071266'),
      (20,'Hamid','Alvi','hamidalvi@gmail.com','12 A DHA Phase 2','0300 7071266');
```

After inserting data, Cust_init table should look like this:

```
NewCustID   |DW_CustID  |FirstName  |LastName   |Email                  |MailingAddress         |Phone
NULL        |   11      |Ahmad      |Raza       |ahmaddba@gmail.com     |154 Zafarwal           |0345 2876543
NULL        |   12      |Iftikhan   |Khan       |iffikhan@gmail.com     |12 A DHA Phase         |0303 56871298
NULL        |   13      |Iftikhan   |Khan       |iffikhan@gmail.com     |12 A DHA Phase         |0303 56871298
NULL        |   14      |Mohsin     |Khan       |mohsinkaz@gmail.com    |55 shadab nagar        |0301 6791255
NULL        |   15      |Mohsin     |Khan       |mohsinkaz@gmail.com    |55 shadab nagar        |0301 6791255
NULL        |   16      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
NULL        |   17      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
NULL        |   18      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
NULL        |   19      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
NULL        |   20      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
```

**Phase 1**
I want to identify duplicate records based on FirstName, LastName, Email and assign new keys to NewCustID(starting numeric number is going to 1 initially
then max value + 1 after initial load). NewCustID numeric keys will start from 1 and unique for each record except for duplicates. In case of duplicate, single
numeric key should be associated with all related duplicate records.

After assigning NewCustID , the Cust_init table should look like following.

```
NewCustID   |DW_CustID  |FirstName  |LastName   |Email                  |MailingAddress         |Phone
1           |   11      |Ahmad      |Raza       |ahmaddba@gmail.com     |154 Zafarwal           |0345 2876543
2           |   12      |Iftikhan   |Khan       |iffikhan@gmail.com     |12 A DHA Phase         |0303 56871298
2           |   13      |Iftikhan   |Khan       |iffikhan@gmail.com     |12 A DHA Phase         |0303 56871298
3           |   14      |Mohsin     |Khan       |mohsinkaz@gmail.com    |55 shadab nagar        |0301 6791255
3           |   15      |Mohsin     |Khan       |mohsinkaz@gmail.com    |55 shadab nagar        |0301 6791255
4           |   16      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
4           |   17      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
4           |   18      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
4           |   19      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
4           |   20      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
```

**Phase 2**
After assigning NewCustID in Cust_Init table, I want to copy only unique rows to table MergedCust. Keeping just one row with min DW_CustID for duplicate records.

```
NewCustID   |DW_CustID  |FirstName  |LastName   |Email                  |MailingAddress         |Phone
1           |   11      |Ahmad      |Raza       |ahmaddba@gmail.com     |154 Zafarwal           |0345 2876543
2           |   12      |Iftikhan   |Khan       |iffikhan@gmail.com     |12 A DHA Phase         |0303 56871298
3           |   14      |Mohsin     |Khan       |mohsinkaz@gmail.com    |55 shadab nagar        |0301 6791255
4           |   16      |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com    |12 A DHA Phase 2       |0300 7071266
```

**My Effort**
I have come up with following sql to rank rows with same number for duplicates but not sure how to update NewCustID correctly.

```sql
;WITH cte as (
    SELECT  NewCustID, DW_CustID, FirstName,LastName, Email, MailAddress, Phone,
            dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName , LastName, Email ) as RN
    FROM dbo.cust_init 
)
select RN,FirstName , LastName, Email 
from cte
```

The result set looks like following, I would like to assign RN to NewCustID initially to see if it fulfills the purpose.

```
RN  |FirstName  |LastName   |Email
1   |Ahmad      |Raza       |ahmaddba@gmail.com
2   |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com
2   |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com
2   |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com
2   |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com
2   |Hamid      |Alvi       |hamidalvi@gmail.com
3   |Iftikhan   |Khan       |iffikhan@gmail.com
3   |Iftikhan   |Khan       |iffikhan@gmail.com
4   |Mohsin     |Khan       |mohsinkaz@gmail.com
4   |Mohsin     |Khan       |mohsinkaz@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult and computationally expensive problem, because it involves walking a graph along three different types of edges (email addresses, phones, and mail addresses).

To approach this with a single query, you can use recursive CTEs.  Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support arrays, so avoiding cycles requires keeping track of the earlier ids you have hit, and that is a lot of string operations.

Here is the query:

```
with cte as (
      select dw_custId, dw_custId as other_ci,
             convert(varchar(max), concat(',', dw_custId, ',')) as cis,
             convert(varchar(max), ',' + email + ',') as emails,
             convert(varchar(max), ',' + phone + ',') as phones,
             convert(varchar(max), ',' + mailaddress + ',') as mailaddresses,
             1 as lev
      from cust_init
      union all
      select cte.dw_custId, ci.dw_custId,
             concat(cte.cis, ci.dw_custId, ','),
             (case when cte.emails not like concat('%,', ci.email, ',%') then concat(cte.emails, ci.email, ',') else cte.emails end),
             (case when cte.phones not like concat('%,', ci.phone, ',%') then concat(cte.phones, ci.phone, ',') else cte.phones end),
             (case when cte.mailaddresses not like concat('%,', ci.mailaddress, ',%') then concat(cte.mailaddresses, ci.mailaddress, ',') else cte.mailaddresses end),
             lev + 1
      from cte join
           cust_init ci
           on cte.emails like concat('%,', ci.email, ',%') or
              cte.phones = concat('%,', ci.phone, ',%') or
              cte.mailaddresses = concat('%,', ci.mailaddress, ',%')
      where cte.cis not like concat('%,', ci.dw_custId, ',%') and lev < 10
     )
select dw_custid, min(other_ci), dense_rank() over (order by min(other_ci)) as newCustId
from cte
group by dw_custid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e1075b38418ebadb010afbfa1aa7adc) is the db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

You can use this in an `update`:

```
with cte ( . . . )
update t2
    set newCustId = x.newCustId
    from (select dw_custid, min(other_ci), dense_rank() over (order by min(other_ci)) as newCustId
          from cte
          group by dw_custid
         ) x join
         table2 t2
         on t2.dw_custid = x.dw_custid;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind response Gordon. There is no restriction of handling this case in a single query, there can be multiple queries to solve this problem and probably, i will combine them in a stored procedure.

Comment: Gordon, can you add another example of assigning NewCustID to existing table using update statements? No restriction to do in a single query, multiple queries would rather be better and easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH customers AS (
  SELECT 
    Dense_rank() OVER(
      ORDER BY 
        c.firstname, 
        c.lastname, 
        c.email
    ) AS rn, 
    * 
  FROM 
    #cust_init AS c) 
  INSERT INTO #mergedcust 
  SELECT 
    c.rn AS newcustid, 
    -1 AS DW_CustID, 
    c.firstname, 
    c.lastname, 
    c.email, 
    c.mailaddress, 
    c.phone 
  FROM 
    customers AS c 
  GROUP BY 
    c.rn, 
    c.firstname, 
    c.lastname, 
    c.email, 
    c.mailaddress, 
    c.phone;
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  #mergedcust
```

Comment: Your answer is partially correct for Phase 2 where i want to move unique records to mergedcust table but lacking DW_CustID from source table cust_init. I think you missed the Phase 1 where i need to update NewCustID in the source table cust_init.

Comment: I was replying to a portion of your original question that you have deleted.

Comment: I never deleted anything rather updated the question while i was posting it. It might not be really clear but updating Keys was always the first part. Anyways, I appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.min_cust_id) NewCustID,
B.DW_CustID,
B.FirstName,
B.LastName,
B.Email,
B.MailAddress,
B.Phone
FROM 
(
    SELECT email, MIN(dw_custID) min_cust_id
    FROM cust_init
    GROUP BY EMAIL
)A
INNER JOIN cust_init B ON A.min_cust_id = B.DW_CustID
```

Comment: This does not serve the purpose, it just returns the result set based on email ordering and involves unnecessary joins. I showed my effort which returns same result using `CTE` and `dense_rank`.

Comment: @FarIDM please check the script again. I have updated the script.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the desired result you posted above.  Just use ROW_NUMBER to number your duplicates and then take the first one.

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT NewCustID, DW_custID,FirstName,LastName,Email,MailAddress,Phone, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by NewCustID ORDER BY NewCustID) RN
from #Cust_init
)

INSERT INTO #MergedCust
select NewCustID,DW_custID,FirstName,LastName,Email,MailAddress,Phone 
from CTE where RN = 1

SELECT * from #MergedCust
```

**EDIT:**
Given your data above I assumed you had already figured out how to assign the NewCustID.  Here is how I did it:

```
UPDATE #Cust_init set NewCustID =  DR
       FROM #Cust_init t1
       INNER JOIN (SELECT dw_custid, DENSE_RANK () OVER(order by firstname,lastname,email) DR from #Cust_init) t2
       on t1.DW_CustID = t2.DW_CustID
```

Comment: This just returns one row with DW_CustID = 11 instead of the required 4 rows. Also, you missed the first part where new keys should be assigned to NewCustID first and then inserting unique records in table `mergedcust`.